# Convexity of trace$(X^{-1})$

Tags: convex-geometry

Prove that the function $$ f(X) = \operatorname{trace}(X^{−1}) $$ is convex on the domain $S^n_{++}$.

I was given the hint to try using line restriction. So I am trying to prove that $$ g(t) = f(x+ty) $$ is convex for all x $\epsilon $ $ S^{n}_{++} $ and y $\epsilon$ $ R^n $ such that $ \{ t :x+ty \ \epsilon \  S^{n}_{++} \} $. I have tried calculating the hessian matrix but I am getting confused on how to take the gradient of a matrix and the trace function.

Comment: What is $Sn++$ ?

Comment: $ S_{n}^{++} $ is the set of square, symmetric, positive definite matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p,\ q\in S^+$, then a linear combination $
c(t)=tp +(1-t)q$ is symmetric.
If $p,\ q$ are close, then $c(t)$ is positive definite.

Note that $c(t)=p+tV$, where $V$ is an any symmetric matrix, is a
shortest path. In further,
$$ c (t)^{-1}= p^{-1}-tp^{-1}Vp^{-1} -t^2 p^{-1} Vp^{-1} Vp^{-1}
+\cdots
$$

Hence $$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\ f\circ c\ (t) =-2\cdot {\rm trace}\
p^{-1} Vp^{-1} Vp^{-1} \leq 0$$ since $ p^{-1} Vp^{-1} Vp^{-1} $ is
non-negative definite : If $\langle\ ,\ \rangle$ is an inner
product, and $u$ is a vector, then $$
 \langle p^{-1} Vp^{-1} Vp^{-1} u,u\rangle   =
 \langle p^{-1} Vp^{-1} u,Vp^{-1}u\rangle \geq 0 $$

Comment: There is a flaw in $c(t)^{-1}$, exactly $c(t)^{-1} = p^{-1} - tp^{-1}Vp^{-1} + t^2p^{-1}Vp^{-1}Vp^{-1} + \cdots$, then 
$$
f^{\prime\prime}(c(t)) = 2 tr(p^{-1} V p^{-1} V p^{-1}) \ge 0
$$
hence $f(c(t))$ is convex